# Dash python select multiple dates from Datepicker

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

Currently using a datepicker the Selection of a single date is possible in Dash
How can Multiple dates be selected with comma seperation

I have tried DatepickerRange, but i am looking for selecting the randoms in custom order

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerSingle(
        id='my-date-picker-single',
        min_date_allowed=dt(1995, 8, 5),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2017, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=dt(2017, 8, 5),
        date=str(dt(2017, 8, 25, 23, 59, 59))
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-single')
])
```